# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HandBluetooth", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

```
warning: ignoring file /Users/-----/Desktop/CSHandData/CSHandData/CSHandBag/libCSHand.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/-----/Desktop/CSHandData/CSHandData/CSHandBag/libCSHand.a


1.. "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HandBluetooth", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
2.. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

add Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Add .m File But I have No solution Please Suggest solve this error

Comment: are you tried this in your simulator

Comment: no, Problem In Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **libCSHand.a does not have x86_64 architecture** , you can add x86_64 to your static framework.

You can CHECK supported architecture by using this commands.

1. lipo -info libCSHand.a
2. xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libCSHand.a
3. file libCSHand.a